# How to add content to file and remove it to another location

Tags: powershell, location

I need to add some text to a file and remove file to another location after that.
I am using:

```
Get-ChildItem \\serverpath\tmp -Recurse -Filter *.txt| Foreach-Object{(add-Content $_.FullName -value ';;;')}

Get-ChildItem \\serverpath\tmp -Recurse -Filter *.txt| Foreach-Object{
  Move-Item \\serverpath\tmp\$($_.Name) -Destination "\\serverpath\$($_.Name)"}
```

How to do this without having twice `Get-ChildItem` sentence? We have process which write data, so I would like to be sure that files are not transfered without adding `;;;` at end of files.

Answer (score 0):

You can do both within the same loop:

```
$destinationPath = '\\serverpath\NewLocation'
Get-ChildItem -Path '\\serverpath\tmp' -Recurse -Filter '*.txt'| Foreach-Object {
    $_ | Add-Content -Value ';;;'
    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $destinationPath
}
```